# Yum install error (mysql-devel) depsolve

Tags: centos, yum

I get the following error on yum install mysql-devel. Can anyone help? I dont have this in my /etc/yum.conf exclude list.

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
mysql-server-5.0.45-7.el5.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: mysql = 5.0.45-7.el5 is needed by package mysql-server-5.0.45-7.el5.x86_64 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: mysql = 5.0.45-7.el5 is needed by package mysql-server-5.0.45-7.el5.x86_64 (installed)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Things I'd try:

```
yum clean all ; yum install mysql-devel
```

If it was an intermittent problem with the yum repo you're using, that could fix it.

```
rpm -qa ^mysql\*
```

It's also possible that you have duplicate copies of the same package installed.  I've seen very similar errors to what you describe when that happened.